# Turn cells in a column a color based on another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My spreadsheet has conditional formatting that turns a cell in Column M a color when the cell value is NOT "N/A."  How do I also change the color in Column A based on the corresponding cell in Column M?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to make a new conditional formatting rule and apply the rule to column A in your excel sheet.

First, click the A at the top of Column A to highlight the entire column (or highlight only the cells in column A that you want the rule to apply to). Next, On the home tab, look in the ribbon for "Conditional Formatting." Click it, then choose New Rule.  In the "Format Values where this formula is true" box, type in the formula you need.

For your example, you'll need something like `=M1="Text"`.  Excel will automatically increment the number after the M, so don't worry about that. Next click "Format..." and choose how you want to format the cell based upon the expression.  Click Ok, and it should be ready to go.

In the example above, if the cell M1 is equal to the word "Text" (without quotes), it will be true, and the conditional formatting will be applied to the cell.

Comment: Was it what you were looking for?